# Cookie Security Issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, security, cookies

I'm creating a authentication route where user can login and u know the rest.
So after login im creating a refresh token (using JWT) which valid for 7 days, and with help of that refresh token i create access token (valid for 15 min) for logging in a users.
So to access a refresh token in frontend im storing this to cookie i.e `refreshToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6I..."` (whatever that string is). The problem is if any one access this refresh token and store it manually he can login as that user, until that jwt token expires. Im not storing Access token in cookie.
So What could be the solution for this, im thinking of storing refresh_token in user DB and update as user login.
Any suggestions will really appreciated :)

Comment: Mark it as secure and httpOnly. For invalidation you can rotate keys, in case it got stolen.

Comment: You don't need to store it in dB, what else you can do is to store your accesstoken in localstorage , when user enter to the dashboard send a post request to check whether this token is valid or not (using useEffect() hook).

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Can u justify what u meant by rotate keys please?